# Twitter find referal tweet

Tags: twitter

This is nuts.

I have quite some traffic coming on my site and it apparently comes from one tweet: `t.co/<HASH>`

[image]

But after searching for quite some time, I can't find a way to reach back the tweet.

Tried to google `tweeter backlink` and co, tried the [twitter advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en) with my domain name, etc. but nothing works... All I find are obscure marketing website I really don't want to visit...

Can't twitter tell me which tweet does it originates from? Or any other clean-ish tool?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I googled the`"t.co/<HASH>"` URL with quotes and suddenly it appeared.

Power to google once again...